# How to run a windmill test script

Tags: automated-tests, web-testing, windmill

I have recorded some interactions with windmill and when I hit save I get the following (python) script:

```
# Generated by the windmill services transformer
from windmill.authoring import WindmillTestClient

def test_recordingSuite0():
    client = WindmillTestClient(__name__)

    client.type(text=u'Hello World', id=u'lst-ib')
    client.click(link=u'Hello world program - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia')
    client.waits.forPageLoad(timeout=u'20000')
```

Now I don't have any clue how to run this. At the end I need a script with which I can run 100 tests at the same time.

However, if I get one test running and it is easy to parallelize it with python. But right now I can't run this simple test.

I hope someone can help me :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply run by pasting the output script from windmill into a file named as *.py and then you execute the following command

```
windmill chrome test=./[directory containing your *.py files] http://www.google.com
```

You can also specify directly the name of the test file.

If you want to run the script in parallel, then you can just execute those commands in separate terminals. This works so far only with chrome. Firefox is complaining if there more than one instance open.